# Can I reset my stats after i have used my prestige reward?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I would like to reset my stats on black ops 2, but I have already used my token to create another class. Is there a way i can do this? If i have to delete the game from my hard drive and re-install I would do it but rather avoid it as how its a lengthy download and i dont want to lose my nuketown zombies

Answer (score 1):

You can use a prestige token to reset your stats which will bring you to level 1 of no prestige and no stats at all. To do so go into prestige mode and then when you click on prestige awards I believe it's `fresh start` that you're looking for. Once you do that it will reset all your stats as if it was the first time that you've played the game, or rather when you first picked up the game and loaded multiplayer. This will not effect your zombies, it would only effect your multiplayer ranks and stats. You can refer to this [video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oekr1UvVZgo) that talks about it. If you have any questions let me know so that I can update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To reset your stats without going through the lengthy download you would have to prestige again which doesnt take too much time in black ops 2.